# Using many ands in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am having problems using many and statements in the `WHERE` statement.

When I have this line of PHP:

```
$where .= " AND post_date >= '$app_time'";
```

It works just fine, however when introducing this:

```
$where .= " AND post_date >= '$app_time' AND post_date <= '$app_timeTwo'";
```

It causes it to display results which do NOT fit in between 2 times. `$app_time` and `$app_timeTwo` are a `_$GET[''];` parameter, sent from a URL from an iPhone app. They are the correct format.

Any reason why using two ands breaks it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of the post_date column. Its probably trying to do a string compare and that is why you are getting unexpected results

Comment: Please provide examples of `$app_time` and `$app_timeTwo`.

Comment: Please show the complete where clause that you are building. The result will depend on the whole where clause and therefore we need to see it all.

Comment: @RiggsFolly not to mention the table definition as well

Answer (score 1):

Use "between" clause instead of using multiple "and" in second query and make sure that datatype of "post_date" is datetime ..

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$where .= " AND post_date BETWEEN '$app_time' AND '$app_timeTwo'";
```

Comment: If the OPs query is failing, then this one is likely to as well. It is more likely a poor column definition or poor query params causing the unexpected results

Comment: @Anigel OP have not given the structure of table. So I can guess that there may be problem.

Comment: @Anigel I think OP is comparing the time with the datetime.